# Using Solr for keeping an Audit of event history

Tags: database, solr

I need to keep an audit of events and need quick querying over this audit. Audit should be kept online for 7 years. Around 100k events per day, but could possibly increase. Events are usually resent multiple times. Events are large enough that I will see a benefit from not storing them more than once.

Logically, in denormalised JSON, my event looks like this:

```
{
    correlationIds: [],
    payload: "",
    history: [
        {
            uniquePublishId: "",
            time: "",
            consumed: [
                {
                    system: "",
                    time: "",
                    audit: ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Each event can be published multiple times, each time it is published, a new item is added to the `history` array. Each time an event is consumed, an item is added to the `consumed` array.

`correlationIds` is an array of strings that can be used to search for the event so will include each of the `uniquePublishId`s for each time it is published.

Typical queries that will be run, that will expect a near-instant response:

- Find an event by its `uniquePublishId`
- Find events by a correlation id.
- Find events by a publish date/time-range
- Find events by a consumption date/time-range
- Find events that have been published but not consumed by a particular `system`

Now I am thinking of using Solr to store this to give me the quick searching I want, however I am wondering how best to store this that will allow me to search efficiently.

Document limit per collection is 2.1billion IIRC, but I guess I can store in multiple collections, by year.

**So my question:**

How do I store these events to ensure a fast search time? I don't want to have to pull out the message payload every-time I want to add a new event publish to the `history`, or when I add an event consumed to the `consumed` array.

From googling, it looks like I can store them in separate collections and do a cross collection join - but I don't know how this affects performance. Now that has lead me to the realm of normalized, so should I even be using Solr?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is perfect for Solr, but use Solr Cloud, and preferably store indexes on HDFS for optimal distribution of reads across N data nodes. Solr 5.3 provides [json faceting](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/) which provides rich query capabilities (and will cover the questions you listed above).

36+ million events per year isn't that much to index or search. As you mentioned, partition by year is perfect.

Joining across multiple collections can present challenges (e.g., maintenance can cause wrong results, complex queries to write, etc.)

I did a similar setup but for tweets. Indexed 1.44 billion tweets partitioned by month. Each tweet JSON is about 2K on disk. So on
disk Solr size is about 1TB. Query time is on average 3 seconds on 
a 5-data node Hadoop cluster.